# Pre-define calls in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, serialization

I'm trying to use a nest serializer in Django REST Framewordk.

Like the below documentation mentioned.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

But Now I met a problem, that I want to call a nesting serializer which is defined below that point.

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')

class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('order', 'title')
```

And because of some referencing restrictions, I cannot move that class up.

How to solve the problem in this case?

Comment: @SaurabhGoyal it has some circular referencing.

Comment: If you have problem of circular imports. Import those inside of the serializers. So that you can get ride of those problems.